# How to change position of clear button in UISearchBar?

Tags: swift

**I want to change the position of clear button in UISearchBar**
I'm customizing the search bar according to some design issues. I make all of the changes by reaching the UITextField inside the UISearchBar. With the clearButtonRect i can get the rectange but i can not change.

```
        if let searchTextField = value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
            
            searchTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                searchTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(height)),
                searchTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
                searchTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
                searchTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor, constant: 0)
            ])

            searchTextField.clipsToBounds = true
            searchTextField.font = UIFont.regularDMSans(of: 17)
            searchTextField.textColor = .textLight
            searchTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 20
            searchTextField.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
            searchTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.createEventDivider.cgColor
            
            if !shouldShowSearchIcon {
                setImage(UIImage(), for: .search, state: .normal)
            }

            let offset = UIOffset(horizontal: 13, vertical: 0)
            setPositionAdjustment(offset, for: .search)
        
        }
```

[the button with x on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZWLc.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
let offset = UIOffset(horizontal: 13, vertical: 0) 
setPositionAdjustment(offset, for: .clear)
```